# Draggable widgets for web content

Tags: asp.net, draggable, sitefinity

How i can create draggable widgets for web content like sitefinity.For example contact form, image slider, page layout,etc.Can you help me about this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using ASP.NET, why not use the [Web Parts controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0s9t4ck%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which already have this functionality.  I know [Telerik also has a control](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/dock/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx) for this too.  That would be the easiest way, but you could build your own using JQuery draggable/droppable plugins.  However, these do not save their state across postbacks.